Best way to measure days between dates
I'm facing an issue where startDate is 1 January 2025 and endDate is 31 March 2025. Between these 2 dates is 90 days. But my code is calculating 89 days.
I've seen the math of the code excludes the first partial day (from midnight to 06:00) on 2025-01-01, which results in 89 full days instead of 90 days.
startDate: 2025-01-01 06:00:00 +0000
endDate: 2025-03-31 06:00:00 +0000
This is my function:
func daysBetweenDates() -> Int? {
    guard let selectedStartDate = selectedStartDate?.date else { return nil }
    guard let selectedEndDate = selectedEndDate?.date else { return 0 }

    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: selectedStartDate, to: selectedEndDate)

    return dateComponents.day
}

What I've tried is to reset the hours to 0 so it can take the full day and return 90 days.
Like this:
func daysBetweenDates() -> Int? {
     guard let selectedStartDate = selectedStartDate?.date else { return nil }
     guard let selectedEndDate = selectedEndDate?.date else { return 0 }

     var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
     calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0) ?? .current

     let cleanMidNightStartDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: selectedStartDate)
     let cleanMidNightEndDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: selectedEndDate.addingTimeInterval(24 * 60 * 60))

     let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: cleanMidNightStartDate, to: cleanMidNightEndDate)
     let daysCount = dateComponents.day ?? 0

     return daysCount
 }

This worked for that date specifically but when I tried to change the date, for example
startDate: 18 December 2024.
endDate: 18 March 2025,
between those dates we have 90 days but this function now reads 91.
What I'm looking is a clever solution for this problem so I can have the best possible quality code.

24 * 60 * 60, don’t use this kind of math when dealing with dates. Use the Calendar class to add one day instead

but adding another day will still be a problem if the date is changed? @JoakimDanielson

The difference between 1 January 2025 at 0600 to 31 March 2025 at 0600 is 89 days, not 90. That's a different calculation than the number of inclusive days from 1 January 2025 to 31 March 2025 (which is a total of 90 days). And the difference between 18 Dec 2024 at 0600 and 18 March 2025 at 0600 is 90 days but the inclusive count is 91. Your original code would be correct as-is for both date ranges if the goal is to calculate the difference in whole days. If you want the inclusive count of days then simply as a + 1 to the return statement.

@HangarRash but by doing that it will be wrong for other cases and will add +1 date if the user selects for example   18 Dec 2024 at 0600 and 18 March 2025 at 0600
90 + 1, how can I track this special cases to add +1?

@ZeroCooL No, it won't be wrong. Your assumption about the number of days is incorrect. Your statement about the actual number of days between the two date ranges you posted in your question are incorrect.

I agree with HangarRash - Either you don't want to include the partial day, in which case your original code gives you the answer - 89 & 90 or you want to include the partial day, so you get 90 & 91

Your code gives the correct answer, depending on how you interpret the last day.
Consider the trivial case from 2025-01-01 06:00 to 2025-01-02 06:00 - One 24 hour period has elapsed, and given this input your code will output '1', even though it involves two different "days" on the calendar.
For the values in your question, 2025-01-01 06:00 to 2025-03-31 06:00, 89 24 hour periods have elapsed and, again, your code gives the correct answer.
Where you will get confused is if you simply add the number of days in the months - 31 + 28 + 31=90. This is incorrect because it is counting from midnight on the 1st of January to 23:59:59 on the 31st of March - An extra 24 hours, which is why you think that the answer should be 90.
If you get a calendar and put your finger on the 1st of January and count every time you move it to the next date, then you will find that you have moved your finger 89 times when it gets to March 31.
If you don't care about the time component and you want to count whole days, just add 1 as HangarRash suggested.
